# Not able to plot multiple lines (data series) in one chart in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, line-plot

Here is my R code: -

```
x <- c(gross.year.df$Reporting.Year)

y1 <- c(gross.year.df$Gross.Revenue)
y2 <- c(net.year.df$Net.Revenue)
y3 <- c(royalty.year.df$Royalty.Payable)


# Plot the first data series using plot()
plot(x, log(y1), type="o", col="red", pch="o", xlab ="Year",  ylab="($)", lty=1)


# Add second data series to the same chart using points() and lines()
points(x, log(y2), col="yellow", pch="*")
lines(x, y2, col="yellow",lty=2)


# Add third data series to the same chart using points() and lines()
points(x, log(y3), col="green",pch="+")
lines(x, y3, col="green", lty=3)


# Add a legend in top left corner of chart at (x, y) coordinates = (1, 19)
legend(1,19,legend=c("Gross Revenue","Net Revenue","Royalty Payable"), col=c("red","yellow","green"),
                                   pch=c("o","*","+"),lty=c(1,2,3), ncol=1)
```

Here are the values of x: -

```
2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
```

Here are the values of y1: -

```
22659123750 37017041140 37178962075 51268667790 24805669463 63423778139
```

Here are the values of y2: -

```
2482747717  7174668076  4934120605 12990816071  3511522049 20201825187
```

Here are the values of y3: -

```
843040394 2480251532 2738473691 4836819255 1067122211 7703784912
```

What I am expecting is to get 3 lines plotted in the above graph but the output of my code is that only the first line is showing up. I am not able to debug the problem. I also tried to take the `"log"` of `y-axis` but still nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You values are out of scale.

I added the parameter `ylim=c(0,2e10)` to fit all in the plot. It sets the range of y coordinates in the plot. If you do not set it, it will be automatically determined by te data in the first `plot` function, which is not appropiate for the other data you plot. However, the smallest values like `log(y3)` for sure will lie indistinguishable in the x axis.
Consider plotting the values in different plots.

```
x=c(2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021)
y1=c(22659123750,37017041140,37178962075,51268667790,24805669463,63423778139)
y2=c(2482747717,7174668076,4934120605,12990816071,3511522049,20201825187)
y3=c(843040394,2480251532,2738473691,4836819255,1067122211,7703784912)


# Plot the first data series using plot()
plot(x, log(y1), type="o", col="red", pch="o", xlab ="Year",  ylab="($)", lty=1, ylim = c(0,4e10))


# Add second data series to the same chart using points() and lines()
points(x, log(y2), col="yellow", pch="*")
lines(x, y2, col="yellow",lty=2)


# Add third data series to the same chart using points() and lines()
points(x, log(y3), col="green",pch="+")
lines(x, y3, col="green", lty=3)


# Add a legend in top left corner of chart at (x, y) coordinates = (1, 19)
legend(1,19,legend=c("Gross Revenue","Net Revenue","Royalty Payable"), col=c("red","yellow","green"),
                                   pch=c("o","*","+"),lty=c(1,2,3), ncol=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I am executing your code, the "red" line is flat which is not accurate. Also I am not able to get legend as well.

Comment: Because in the red line you're taking logarithms, which is 10 orders of magnitude smaller than the yellow or green `lines` (at which you are not taking logarithms) . Consider taking all logarithm and change ylim accordingly.